# Can I run TensorFlow on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, c++

I wan't to know if TensorFlow (http://tensorflow.org/) can be used on the Raspberry Pi both the Python API and the C++?

Comment: nightly wheel file builds [here](http://ci.tensorflow.org/) too, search for pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the above link. you can directly install latest tensorflow on any raspberry pi (ARMV7) device from here:

http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-python3/lastSuccessfulBuild/

Answer (score 11):

There's now a python package available for Tensorflow on RaspberryPi aptly called, [tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/).